# Load commented properties to Properties object in java

Tags: java, properties, load, comments

I'm trying to load properties to a Properties object in java using `load(new FileReader())` method. All the properties are loaded except the properties start with(#) commented ones. How to load these commented properties to the Properties object using java API. Only manual way?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could propose you to extend the `java.util.Properties` class to override this specificities but it was not designed for it : many things are hardcoded and not overridable. So you should do entire copy-paste of methods with little modification.
For example, at a time, the LineReader used in internal does that when you load a properties file  :

```
 if (isNewLine) {
                isNewLine = false;
                if (c == '#' || c == '!') {
                    isCommentLine = true;
                    continue;
                }
 }
```

The `#` is hardcoded.

**Edit**

Another way could be read line by line the proprties file,  remove the first char if it is  `#` and write the read line, modified if needed, in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. then you could load the properties with a `ByteArrayInputStream` from  `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`.

Here a possible implementation with a unit test :

With as input `myProp.properties` :

```
dog=woof
#cat=meow
```

The unit test :

```
@Test
public void loadAllPropsIncludingCommented() throws Exception {

    // check properties commented not retrieved
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(LoadCommentedProp.class.getResourceAsStream("/myProp.properties"));
    Assert.assertEquals("woof", properties.get("dog"));
    Assert.assertNull(properties.get("cat"));

    // action
    BufferedReader bufferedIs = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LoadCommentedProp.class.getResource("/myProp.properties").getFile()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String currentLine = null;
    while ((currentLine = bufferedIs.readLine()) != null) {
        currentLine = currentLine.replaceFirst("^(#)+", "");
        out.write((currentLine + "\n").getBytes());
    }
    bufferedIs.close();
    out.close();

    // assertion
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(in);
    Assert.assertEquals("woof", properties.get("dog"));
    Assert.assertEquals("meow", properties.get("cat"));
}
```